# background gimbal detection of visits (receivedSighting/didArrive/didDepart)?

Tags: ios, core-location, ibeacon

how can i detect if a gimbal beacon has left a particular region when app is in background? I tried with didDepart delegate method but its getting called only after 15 mins ,any solution for thi

Answer (score 0):

This maybe a little bit late but still reply to your question. Just in case someone out there don't know.Actually we can set the value for departure event (didDepart) in background mode. Here is an example:

```
NSMutableDictionary *options = [NSMutableDictionary new];
[options setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:FYXSightingOptionSignalStrengthWindowNone] forKey:FYXSightingOptionSignalStrengthWindowKey];
[options setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:5] forKey:FYXVisitOptionDepartureIntervalInSecondsKey];
[options setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:120] forKey:FYXVisitOptionBackgroundDepartureIntervalInSecondsKey];
[options setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:-60] forKey:FYXVisitOptionArrivalRSSIKey];
[options setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:-70] forKey:FYXVisitOptionDepartureRSSIKey];
[self.visitManager startWithOptions:options];
```